# Windows Server 2008 server information display

Tags: windows-server-2008

Does anyone know how to display the server information (name, ip, cpu, etc) on the desktop background? I've seen it used, but i have no idea how to show it.

Thanks...

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/58521/server-name-in-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a free tool from the sysinternals.com suite called BGInfo.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx

Read this URL and it will show you how to configure/automate what it displays.

Mark Ringo

Answer (score 1):

[BgInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo) from Microsoft Sysinternals is probably the one you've seen.

[image: BgInfo]